# Where is the ria service config when WCF Ria Services Link is used?

Tags: ria, silverlight-5.0

we currently set **WCF RIA Services Link** from  the Silverlight client, I currently looking for the config file to changes some wcf settings. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What settings do you want to change?

Comment: For example, we are uploading a file through ria service, so I need to adjust the maxarray and things related to that. Thanks

Comment: You need to adjust the service endpoints in the website (the one where the services are hosted).

Comment: Hi HiTechMagic, do you mean this part in the web config?               <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

Comment: Thanks. More details in answer below. Really just a starting point for you as there are so many options available in the configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add appropriate settings and behaviors to your service endpoints.

Here is an example of an endpoint behavior that increases maxItemsInObjectGraph:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientMaxItemsInObjectGraphBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

It is referenced using `behaviorConfiguration=` in an endpoint like this:

```
<endpoint contract="AssemblyName.IContactName" 
    address="http://localhost:50101/MyService.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="ClientMaxItemsInObjectGraphBehavior"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Default"
    name="MyServiceEndpoint">
</endpoint>
```

Most of the other settings relate to the service binding which was referenced by `bindingConfiguration=` e.g.:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Default"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                            maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                            maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
```

It is probably easier to study the matching classes and properties than the config files. Configs get messy very fast, but they just reflect a hierarchy of properties at run-time so working backwards from the class documentation may help you understand where the various settings go.